# Expected exception is not caught in Unit Test

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a Unit Test for a class "DbCommand" which in its constructor verifies if the first parameter receives the "?" value. If it does, it throws an ArgumentException.

```
CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC DbCommand (dbConnection AS DbConnection,
                              cInstruction AS CHARACTER):

    IF (dbConnection = ?) THEN
        UNDO, THROW NEW ArgumentException("DbConnection must be valid":U) .
```

In the Unit Test I am assigning the first parameter with the "?" to verify that the exception is thrown. For that I added:

```
@Test (expect="System.ArgumentException").
METHOD PUBLIC VOID TestDbCommand ():

    DEFINE VARIABLE oDbCommand AS DbCommand NO-UNDO .

    oDbCommand = NEW DbCommand(?, "Delete") .
```

But the Unit test fails with the first line of the Failure trace being:
"System.ArgumentException: DbConnection must be vaild"

Even though I am already expecting this? I have a few more places were I am using the exact exception and am able to get it caught in the @Test header. But here it doesn't work.

Comment: Which OE version are you seeing this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @Test annotation needs to use the expected attribute, not "expect" for the expected Exception.

And I'm not 100% sure (never used it before), if ABLUnit supports handling of .NET Exceptions in that way - it might be safer to use an ABL Error class instead.

Comment: The code works as expected if you use `expected` ; and the .NET exceptions are caught/processed properly.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this Peter!